# SELinux и AppArmor: преимущества и недостатки

Tags: linux, selinux, apparmor

В чём основные преимущества и недостатки ограничителей доступа SELinux и AppArmor. И в каких случаях один способ не сможет заменить другой?

Answer (score 2):

Главное их отличие заключается в том, что:

> В дистрибутивах Linux используются два решения: SELinux в RedHat и
>   клонах, а также AppArmor в Ubuntu.

И то и другое поддерживается в ядре, начиная с 2.6.

В двух словах: SELinux более строгий, но и более тяжёлый. AppArmor попроще и полегче. Более подробный анализ тут можно  посмотреть:

https://xakep.ru/2010/10/04/53424/